# NHibernate, Log query execution time?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, log4net

I configured Nhibernate and log4net to log queries executed by nhibernate. Is there any way to log each query execution time?

Answer (score 1):

Just configure your ConversionPattern to use the '%d' parameter. [Look at this example](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/configure-log4net-for-use-with-nhibernate.aspx).

Comment: %d appears to log the date, not the execution time?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [nhibernate profiler](http://nhprof.com/). It has 30 day trial which is enough to figure out what's happening and catch all problems. And it's a nice tool in general - worth buying in case You rely on nhibernate heavily.

Comment: Unfortuantly we're not able to install 3rd party software onto production servers, so we're left with whatever standard tools/logging abilities exist.